# Le cerveau qui « fait des zzzt! zzzt! » et celui faisant des « bulles » ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, onomatopées, connotation

Il arrive que la complexité perçue d'un objet ou les trop nombreux tenants et aboutissants d'un mot, d'une expression ou d'une réflexion puissent laisser perplexe, pantois ou je ne sais trop. C'est à mon avis pour cette raison que je dis parfois dans ce genre de contexte que :

> Mon cerveau fait des zzzt! zzzt!

Je l'écris ainsi parce qu'en fait je ne sais pas comment l'écrire, mais en cherchant, j'ai fait cette association avec le bruit du [courant électrique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatop%C3%A9e#Z) (le court-circuit ?) à petite échelle et sa possible l'onomatopée « zzzt » qui représente bien la prononciation dans l'expression telle que je la connais, même sans savoir exactement si elle est vraiment basée là-dessus... Ce pourrait aussi être une forme de « [vertige](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vertige/81685?q=vertige#80721) » ou de « [buzz](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/buzz?s=t) » du cerveau...

J'ai aussi déjà entendu quelqu'un dire de son cerveau qu'il faisait « des (bu?)[bulle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bulle)s » mais je ne sais pas exactement ce que ça veut dire. Dans une remarque au lexique on a *bulbuler* pour « faire des bruits de bulle (en parlant d'un liquide) » (TLFi) avec son « redoublement expressif » ; je ne sais pas si c'est relié. Tandis qu'au Larousse on identifie *faire des [bulle](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bulle/11670/locution)s* généralement comme une expression populaire pour « faire un éclat, soulever un incident », avec laquelle je ne suis pas familier.

---

- Peut-on expliquer le sens de la locution « mon cerveau fait des zzzt
  zzzt » et indiquer si « mon cerveau fait des bulles/*bubulles* »
  signifie la même chose ; est-ce la bonne onomatopée dans la première,
  une référence à un bruit dans la deuxième ?
- Y a-t-il autre chose (ou un autre bruit ?) que le *cerveau* « fait »,
  de sens similaire ; est-ce généralement avec une connotation
  (positive, négative) ?

Comment: Le cerveau qui fait "zzzt zzzt" c'est la première fois que j'entend ça ! Je suis curieux de savoir d'où cela provient.

Le cerveau qui fait des bulles, ça pourrait venir des bulles qui représentent la pensée dans une bande dessinée ? Ou pourquoi pas de l'expression "avoir le cerveau en ébullition", quand on est dans un état de réflexion intense.

Comment: @Orgoss Pour les _bulles_ en effet ça pourrait être l'idée d'hyperactivité, d'ébullition ou j'ai cru déceler dans un exemple, la colère, et dans un autre, une idée de plaisir, et je ne sais pas exactement ; en plus c'est peut-être peu fréquent, très jeune ou argotisant ; encore une fois je ne sais pas trop. Le zzzt! zzzt! bien c'est l'onomatopée et je suis certain d'avoir dit un truc dont la prononciation colle à ça, pour la stupéfaction aussi peut-être, mais il se peut qu'il n'y ait aucun lien entre ces expressions. J'aimerais y voir plus clair. Merci.

Comment: Svp veuillez voter davantage pour les réponses qui vous conviennent ou en ajouter d'autres. Merci.

Comment: Outre être *en compote* ou en *en bouillie*, le cerveau fait des noeuds et a des crampes. Pour moi les bulles renvoient un peu au *cerveau en ébullition*, une bulle, comme si elle était de savon, se détache de la surface, attire l'attention momentanément, et "poppe", et là la personne s'en rend compte et dit "oups, j'étais ailleurs", ou comme Feelew "oups, j'ai dit une bétise". | Par ailleurs vu la quantité de réponses anecdotiques "je connais telle expression dans tel sens, et je n'ai jamais entendu les autres", une réponse-résumé vaudrait le coup.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Est-ce que _ça chie des bulles_ est une expression reliée ? Je me dis que j'ai du entendre un truc avec des bulles dans un contexte où j'aurais dit l'expression avec le zzzt zzzt alors j'ai fait une association... Merci.

Comment: L'expression avec les bulles pourrait-elle être __tripper des bulles__? Je l'ai souvent entendue et lue, mais serais bien mal à mon aise d'en définir l'étymologie. J'ai du moins cru qu'elle signifie qu'on est dans un agréable état d'ébahissement...

Comment: @deLaDauversière: je dirais que non, pas reliée.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### « Mon cerveau fait des zzzt zzzt »

Selon mes observations, cette expression est habituellement utilisée pour indiquer une grande incompréhension.

Appliquée à soi, une explication trop compliquée ou une séquence d’événements trop embrouillée peut provoquer cet état : le cerveau tente beaucoup, mais sans succès, de lier les informations qui lui arrivent.

Appliquée à un autre *(son cerveau fait zzzt zzzt)*, on indique sa propre incompréhension des agissements de cette personne (par exemple une rire incontrôlable que rien ne semble justifier, une grande excitation ou un flot ininterrompu de paroles incohérentes), agissements que l’on justifie ultimement avec un malfonctionnement temporaire de son cerveau.

Dans tous les cas, c’est un usage plutôt comique et léger que sérieux ou malveillant.

Ainsi que déjà mentionné dans les réponses, ces locutions sont assez peu utilisées à l’écrit. Ça donne le champs libre aux écrivains quant à l’orthographe de l’onomatopée. Je serais très surpris que cette onomatopée soit autre chose que le bruit d’un arc électrique dû à un mauvais contact dans un circuit, ou à un quasi-court-circuit. Il s’agirait en ce cas d’une expression relativement récente dans l’histoire humaine, ces bruits n’étant apparus qu’il y a quelques générations dans la vie quotidienne. On pourrait toujours penser que l’électricité statique est une expérience bien plus ancienne, mais le doublement de l’onomatopée la discarte d’emblée : on parle bien ici d’un flot continu.

La chosification implicite du cerveau humain est-elle due au parallèle dressé entre sa complexe mécanique (pressentie) et celle des moteurs électriques, bien moindre mais plus facile à observer ? Ou bien l’humain se compara-t-il pour rire à l’un de ces nombreux robots ou androïdes de science-fiction, descendants de ces automates qui fascinèrent l’imagination humaine depuis de nombreux siècles ? L’une ou l’autre explication semblent plausibles et d’autres sont assurément envisageables. Comme dans bien des cas, la convergence de plusieurs phénomènes culturels pourrait être la cause tant de la création que du succès (relatif) de l’expression.

Mon utilisation personnelle se rapprocherait davantage de *« dzt dzt »*, pour laquelle je pourrais concevoir que l’on doublât (voire triplât) le *Z* afin de mouiller un peu le son d’un mauvais contact électrique : *« dzzt dzzt »*. Aussi, je n’ai pas tendance à considérer l’onomatopée comme un nom, ainsi que présenté dans la question, mais plutôt comme un son ne requérant aucun article :

> - « Mon cerveau fait *dzzt dzzt* »
> - « J’ai le cerveau qui fait *dzzt dzzt* »

Dans le même esprit d’un circuit électrique dans la tête, nous utilisons souvent chez moi (dans ma petite famille) l’expression *« avoir les fils qui se touchent »*, qui déclare explicitement qu’un court-circuit a eu lieu, généralement pour indiquer qu’une grande colère, un total abasourdissement ou une incompréhensible folie a déferlé sur nos pensées et en a momentanément pris le contrôle.

---

#### « Mon cerveau fait des bulles/bubulles »

Je rencontre rarement cette expression sous cette forme en particulier, mais ma conjointe et sa sœur parlent régulièrement de bulles qui passeraient dans le cerveau :

> - « Il m’est passé une bulle au cerveau »
> - « J’ai eu une bulle au cerveau »

Le contexte de ces utilisations m’a fait penser qu’il s’agissait d’un arrêt momentané du bon fonctionnement du cerveau dû au fait qu’une bulle y est passée, l’analogie étant une fois de plus mécanique : une bulle d’air dans une conduite de carburant provoque un hoquet caractéristique lorsqu’elle arrive au carburateur d’un moteur¹. Ce *hoquet cervical* est une façon comme une autre de s’excuser d’une bêtise que l’on a dite ou faite.

La très imagée expression anglaise *« brainfart »* propose une image similaire, mais là où l’on pourrait concevoir, anachronisme linguistique mis à part, un habitant de l’ancienne Égypte parler de *« pets cervicaux »*, la bulle au cerveau, tout ancienne que soit la bulle dans la culture humaine, me semblerait en ce cas plus contestable, car impliquant la connaissance des moteurs à combustion ou à explosion.

Si *« avoir le cerveau qui fait des bulles »* est aussi utilisé pour signifier autre chose, l’ébullition des idées par exemple a été suggérée, je ne l’ai jamais entendu ou lu, et ne saurais par conséquent en discuter constructivement. Je m’en abstiens donc.

---

La *crampe au cerveau* à laquelle Brac a déjà fait allusion ici a été utilisée il y a quelques années par Serge Fiori dans [cette chanson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VzMvVXa6QQ).

---

> ¹ En commentaire d’autres messages, on a aussi mentionné une analogie possible avec une bulle de savon, qui attire l’attention du penseur (si j’ai bien compris) et la soustrait momentanément aux soucis de ce monde. Les bulles de savon possèdent en effet une certaine qualité hypnotique que je ne nierai pas, et si mon entendement personnel s’accomode mieux de la bulle d’air dans le carburateur (à cause entre autre de la similarité des expressions : comparez *« Il est passé une bulle dans le carburateur »*), il importe de demeurer intéressé aux autres interprétations communes, celles-ci s’avérant parfois plus exactes que les siennes, mais aussi parce que même dans le cas contraire, il arrive qu’elles orientent et expliquent, par leur omniprésence, le devenir, la métamorphose et les nouvelles utilisations d’expressions idiomatiques.

Comment: Merci ! Les _éclairs de génie_ feraient-ils un son différent ? Votre lecture est bien bien intéressante, avec la convergence de phénomènes culturels, la graphie qui amplifie le son et la syntaxe sans préposition, que j'entends aussi. L'emploi avec bulle au singulier m'est complètement étranger mais ailleurs en commentaire on l'a aussi remarqué...

Comment: Les _éclairs de génie_ sont bien entendu de l'électricité statique, mais quel spectacle tout de même! Ça grille l'air environnant, ça craque et claque, c'est éblouissant, et même en gros titres, l'onomatopée en serait grossièrement sous-représentée. Quequ'chose comme **KERRROUFFFSH**, peut-être?

Answer (score 3):

Je ne sais pas pour la France, mais les zzt! zzt! au Québec se disent à la blague à quelqu'un qui aurait oublié quelque chose ou qui aurait agi sans réfléchir. il s'agit en effet simuler un bruit électrique qui évoque un court-circuit ou une mauvaise connexion.

Cela dit, je l'ai souvent entendu, mais je ne l'ai jamais vu écrit. Ça demeure une réaction spontanée d'une personne à une autre devant un fait cocasse résultant d'une erreur.

Pour ce qui est des bulles et le cerveau, jamais entendu. Par contre, j'ai déjà entendu quelqu'un dire que telle chose lui donnait des *crampes au cerveau*, en voulant dire que c'était dur à comprendre.

Comment: Aussi au Québec, j'entends régulièrement dire "*j'ai eu une bulle*", typiquement pour désigner un moment d'inattention, ou un brusque passage du coq à l'âne, parce que l'attention de la personne a été happée par une pensée fugace (la dite bulle).
*Mon cerveau a des bulles*, viendrait de l'idée que notre tête est pleine d'eau et que des fois des bulles d'air y passent, voire éclatent, et donc nous donnent des envies bizarres / des lubies / nous font faire des trucs weirds, sans rapport a la situation.
"Une bulle m'a traversé l'esprit" peut aussi vouloir dire *je viens d'avoir une idée folle*.

Answer (score 1):

> • Peut-on expliquer le sens de la locution « mon cerveau fait des zzzt
>   zzzt » et indiquer si « mon cerveau fait des bulles/bubulles »
>   signifie la même chose ; est-ce la bonne onomatopée dans la première,
>   une référence à un bruit dans la deuxième ?

If I’m interpreting TLFi’s «faire des bruits de bulle (en parlant d'un liquide)» entry for *bulbuler* correctly as describing the motorboat-like sound made by blowing “lip bubbles” (perhaps most often by babies just for the fun of it, but also by anyone trying to imitate a motorboat [or to express frustration with an exaggerated “pffff,” but that use is even more irrelevant here than the "non-pffft" one, imo]), then I would vote for attributing «mon cerveau fait des bulles/bubulles» to its connection with that “motorboat” sound.

Thinking that it is a reference to that sound, however, doesn’t help much to determine what it means and specifically for your question, if it means the same as “Mon cerveau fait des zzzt! zzzt!” (which, although I’d use “b[u]zzzz” in English, I agree accurately describes the sound [and condition/connotation] of an electric circuit [or a mind/brain] that has been  “shorted/fried” [or at least one that is “overloaded”]).

The only way that I can see to make a connection between a brain that is making “motorboat” sounds to one that is “struggling” (for whatever reason) is to conveniently/presumptuously introduce the notion and sound of “sputtering,” which could describe in English the sound of a poorly tuned [motorboat] engine that is struggling and which is perhaps even on the verge of stalling-out completely.
 (Perhaps interestingly enough, [this English example from a book found on *GoogleBooks*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q4Tup0oC4jwC&pg=PT112&lpg=PT112&dq=%22mind+was+sputtering%22&source=bl&ots=t0Ks5HCbUV&sig=5etHiMpkvZANksuF7_1PT1oaZNI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_u9bAvIbUAhUo7YMKHaQACLQQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22mind%20was%20sputtering%22&f=false) even connects the notion of “someone’s mind sputtering” directly to “a bad electrical connection.”"

However, going from irrelevant English examples of “a sputtering mind/brain” to relevant French ones requires more than just finding a good French word for “sputter” ([which is easy enough, thanks to *Reverso*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/sputter)).
 It unfortunately also requires finding French examples of “les cerveaux/esprits/tetes [qui] bafouillent/toussotent” or ones that are described as being “bafouillant(e)s//toussotant(e)s” (which, in light of how few of them exist, is not so easy, thus forcing me to admit defeat and to move on briefly to your second question, with the request that you trust me when I state the painfully obvious, yet equally non-idiomatic truth that: “Mon cerveau bafouille dur en ce moment-là!").

---

> • Y a-t-il autre chose (ou un autre bruit ?) que le cerveau « fait »,
>   de sens similaire ; est-ce généralement avec une connotation
>   (positive, négative) ?

My parenthetical mention above of “b[u]zzzz” as the “word” that I’d use in English to describe an electric sound prompts me to propose:

> [La tête qui bourdonne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bourdonner)
>   (*CNRTL/TLFi*)

for describing a sound(buzzing/ringing) in the head/ears.
Granted, this seems to be an actual medical condition, so it probably has neither positive nor negative connotations (unless you do or don’t suffer from it, of course), but I could see the possibility of this being extended figuratively toward both the positive to imply “energetic/productive brain activity,” and also toward the negative to imply “an obviously/ostensibly active but not very productive brain.”

And finally, although not a sound and perhaps not even a thing, I’ve often been told:

> [Papapoule, t'as le cerveau en compote/bouillie,
>   toi!](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/avoir-le-cerveau-en-compote-en-bouillie.3087527/)
>   (*wordreference.com*)

to describe (negatively, I presume) the mush-like contents and products of my brain.

(Although to the lazy/non-discerning ears of this Anglophone the **bou** in “bouillie” does have a slight phonetic resemblance to “un cerveau qui fait des **bu/bu**lles,” I won’t take that thought any further [to yet another disappointing dead end], in spite of being mildly tempted to do so.)

Answer (score 0):

Ces deux expressions sont compréhensibles, mais pas natives.

Pour zzzt ! zzt ! la compréhension n'est pas 100% certaine, du moins à l'écrit, je crois qu'on dirait plutôt : « ça me fait disjoncter le cerveau.»

Pour les bulles, on pourrait confondre avec des bulles de bande dessinée, du coup peut-être que le recours à l'onomatopée avec « bloub, bloub » serait plus clair.

Les expressions les plus communes à ma connaissance sont :

- Ça me fait fumer le cerveau.
- Ça me fait des nœuds au cerveau.

Comment: Les deux expressions semblent québécoises et pas métropolitaines, mais bel et bien natives.